# What form of verb is "thank" in "thank you"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, morphology, verb-forms

Is the word *thank* in *Thank you!* a verb? If not, what part of speech is it then? If it *is* a verb, is it in the imperative mood? I'm asking because I've seen someone write

> Do thank you!

which sounds wrong to me<sup>1</sup>. If it were an imperative verb, the above would be grammatically correct. That's why I started wondering what form it is morphologically.

---

<sup>1 Is it actually wrong? I understand one could say: *I do thank you.*, but is *Do thank you!* valid? (I suppose it's meant to emphasize *thank you*)</sup>

Comment: As you say *I do thank you* so you know that it really is *(I) thank you* , with *I* in ellipsis. Therefore, there is no special significance to the form of the verb that *thank* is, I suppose.

Comment: @Kris: So... are you implying that *Do thank you!* is valid?

Comment: No. You may not use an ellipsis everywhere. Only where an ellipsis can be interpreted would it make sense and therefore be acceptable.

Comment: @Kris: OK, I see. So you're basically saying that *thank* in *thank you* is indicative mood 1st person singular, just like in *I thank you*. Is that correct?

Comment: I am just saying that *Thank you* is *I Thank you* with an ellipsis.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Thank you." is an abbreviation of "I thank you."  *Thank* is a [performative verb](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/performative-verb.html) — a verb where saying it performs the action itself.

Comment: So it's not at all related to "F**k you"?

Comment: @Tor That's only performative in a metaphorical sense - typically.

Comment: Is "Fuck you!" also an abbreviation of "I fuck you"?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Doubtless in earlier/more considered usages such as *"Damn you!"*, you could have said it was an abbreviated "performative", but that's not really the case with modern *"Fuck you!", *"Bugger it!"*, etc. The profanities have switched to a different, more vague grammatical role. No-one would seriously imagine today that *"Sod it!"* stands in for *"I sodomise it!"*