# Superfluous preposition or required?

Tags: prepositions

I have always written this line:
*Thank you everyone who ___.*

Recently, I was told the proper way is to write it as:
*Thank you to everyone who ____.*

Is "to" a superfluous preposition in this situation since it is understood who you are thanking, or would it be required grammatically?

Answer (score 1):

*Thank you* is a [performative verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57925/142322), but a verb nonetheless. If you substitute the verb *come* for *thank you* in your sentence, you get the following, which highlights the awkwardness of considering the two forms to be the same:

> *Come everyone who ...* vs *Come to everyone who ...*.

Another way of looking at this is that the phrases you quote use a modified version of the phrase [*I thank you*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/265893/142322), in which the single word *thank* is the verb. If we restructure the sentences by reintroducing the *I*, we get:

1. I thank everyone who ... .
2. I say thank you to everyone who ... .

The first is more immediate - it's actually thanking everyone. The second might be construed so as well, but it's a little more distant - it might be alleged that you're only *saying* your thanks, not actually thanking everyone. In practice, though, the second form can be modified further for emphasis: *I say **a big** thank you to everyone who ...*, and both forms can be used to express gratitude.

As a matter of fluency with *thank you* as a performative verb, use your first version (i.e. without *to*).